# System of equations and chain rule

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have this system
$\nabla b(z_1,\ldots,z_m)=\psi^\prime(\theta)\nabla\theta(z_1,\ldots,z_m)$. Where we have

$\theta(z_1,\ldots,z_m)=\sum_i^m z_i$ and $b(z_1,\ldots,z_m)$=$\sum_i^m z_i^2$

What is the expression of $\psi^\prime(\theta)$ in terms of $z$.

Solution:
$\|(2z_1,\ldots,2z_m)^t\|=|\psi^\prime(\theta)|\|(1,\ldots,1)^t\|$

Implies

$|\psi^\prime(\theta)|=\frac{4\sqrt{\sum z_i^2}}{\sqrt{m}}$

What is the sign of $\psi'(\theta)$?

Can I say this

$\text{sign}(\psi'(\theta))=\text{sign}(2z_i)$, for all $i$. That will mean the sign of all $z_i$s are the same. But this is not true.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the terms in your equation for the given expressions for $b$ and $\theta$?

Comment: I have edited the problem. And indeed my problem is with sign of $\psi'(\theta)$. I have solved the entire problem.